# How to capture a specific range of numbers within a larger string?

Tags: regex

I have a 15-digit number followed by a number that can be any length.

For example:

15 digit number + 2 digit number;

15 digit number + 3 digit number;

15 digit number + 10 digit number;

How do I use RegEx to capture the first 15 digits as "Part 1" and the remaining number of digits as "Part 2"?

Comment: What is the separator between the numbers? Can you give some specific example inputs? E.g. "foo 123456789012345+1234 bar"

Comment: Also, what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(\d{15})(\d+)$
```

Explanation:

```
^      Start of string
$      End of string
\d     Any digit
{15}   Repeat 15 times
+      Repeat one or more times.
(...)  Capturing group
```

Comment: I've fixed this answer based on comments on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704444/how-to-capture-a-specific-range-of-numbers-within-a-larger-string) that I assume also apply here.